# Как прокинуть подключение mysql и nodejs в одном docker compose?

Tags: node.js, docker

Пол дня бьюсь, не выходит подключиться.
Поставил 3 пакета, adminer, mysql и node js. adminer нормально подключается к mysql. А вот нода падает с ошибкой

```
original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.27.0.3:3306
botapp-node-1 | at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1571:16) {
botapp-node-1 | errno: -111,
botapp-node-1 | code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
botapp-node-1 | syscall: 'connect',
botapp-node-1 | address: '172.27.0.3',
botapp-node-1 | port: 3306,
botapp-node-1 | fatal: true
botapp-node-1 | }
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    build: ./db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 128Wh
    volumes:
      - ./save/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7080:8080
      
  node:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - 433:433
    volumes:
      - ./save/nodejs-app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
```

Dockerfile в ноде

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /bot

COPY package.json /bot

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g pm2

COPY . .

EXPOSE 433

CMD node index.js
```

Dockerfile в mysql

```
FROM mysql

EXPOSE 3306
```

Сам код подключения

```
const { Sequelize, Op } = require('sequelize');
const dataConnect = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  name: 'passports',
  user: 'root',
  password: '128Wh',
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dataConnect.name, dataConnect.user, dataConnect.password, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: dataConnect.host,
});

try {
  sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```